# opening a link in new tab from a link in a panel

Tags: tabs

Hello i am trying to edit a web page to open this link in a new tab everything i have tried so far makes the link open in the panel or on the existing tab i have tried to Google the answer but have been up able to find anything that i understand. I am new to asp so am after some advice

```
<asp:Panel ID="lblSupportLink" cssclass="login-text" style="color:#344A5C; font-size:13px;          padding-left:0px;" runat="server">Google (<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="var page = window; if(parent != null){page = parent;}page.location.href='http://www.google.com';">http://www.google.com)</a></asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick` attribute from the `<a>` tag but add `target="_blank"` instead.

```
<asp:Panel ID="lblSupportLink" cssclass="login-text" style="color:#344A5C; font-size:13px; padding-left:0px;" runat="server">
  Google (<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">http://www.google.com</a>)
</asp:Panel>
```